# I would like to hide the default databases in phpMyAdmin 5.2

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I would like to hide all databases that I do not create myself.

I have used the configuration,

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['hide_db'] = 'information_schema|performance_schema|mysql';
```

The `information_schema` and `mysql` do not hide. The `performance_schema` is the only one that hides. I would also like to hide `sys` if possible.

Thank you.

Comment: That works in other questions on this subject. Maybe try `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` in case it's case-sensitive.